# Solving $|z|i+2z=\sqrt{3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How one can solve the following complex equation, where $z$ is complex number.

$$|z|i+2z=\sqrt{3}$$

Thank you.

Comment: 21 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$|z|=\frac{\sqrt3-2z}i=2zi-\sqrt3i=i(2z-\sqrt3)$$

If $z=a+ib,2z-\sqrt3=2a-\sqrt3+ib\iff i(2z-\sqrt3)=-b+i(2a-\sqrt3)$

$\displaystyle\implies 2a-\sqrt3=0$

Answer (score 3):

Decomposing into real part and imaginary part is really not needed...

For every solution $z$, $2z=\sqrt3-\mathrm i|z|$ $(\ast)$, in particular the modules must coincide hence $|2z|^2=(\sqrt3)^2+(|z|)^2$, that is, $4|z|^2=3+|z|^2$, or simply, $|z|=1$. Using $(\ast)$ once again, one sees that $2z=\sqrt3-\mathrm i$, hence the value of $z$. Now check that this value of $z$ solves the equation and you are done.

Comment: how did you deduce that |2z|^2 is the size of 2z?

Comment: @Bak1139 I fail to understand your question.

Comment: |2z|^2 is size of 2z but you dont have antyting in the form of a+bi for example...than how do you do it?

Comment: @Bak1139 $|2z|^2$ is the **square** of the **modulus** of $2z$, yes (and not the *size* of $2z$, whatever that would mean) and $(\ast)$ writes $2z$ as the sum of $\sqrt{3}$ (a real number) and $-\mathrm i|z|$ (an imaginary number) hence one knows that $(\Re(2z),\Im(2z))=(\sqrt3,-|z|)$, and the rest follows.

Comment: I meant that root of the square of complex number 2z seems to be its size (vector length in gauss plane) and that you got the squares in second eqution after * after squaring roots on both sides?

Comment: @Bak1139 "Second equation after $(\ast)$" uses $|2z|^2=4|z|^2$ and $(\sqrt3)^2=3$. Is this your question?

Comment: I got it all now, sorry for bothering

Answer (score 1):

See $z$ as $a+ib$ and $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ you need nothing more than that...

$|z|i+2z=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow i\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+2(a+ib)=\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow 2a+i(**)=\sqrt{3}$

Just compare real/imaginary part both sides....

Answer (score 0):

$$|z|i+2z=\sqrt{3}$$

which is also: 
 $$  \sqrt {a^2+b^2}i+2a+2bi=\sqrt{3} +0i$$
 compare real and imaginary part concordantly;

You'll get the system:

$ \sqrt {a^2+b^2} +2b= 0$

and

$ 2a= \sqrt{3}$

Solve for $a$ and $ b$, thus you'll find the requested $z$.